# How to "update" width/height of a node after scaling a SVG?

Tags: svg, javafx, tornadofx

I have a bit of an issue here..

I'm trying to have a `svgpath` be a background image by using it in a `stackpane`. I have a set-up like this:

[image: beautiful layout]

Where that grey triangle is a `svgpath` (just a basic one for testing purposes). Now that SVG is located inside an `hbox` like so:

```
class mView : View() {
  override val root = vbox {
    label("test text") {
    //label styles
    }

    hbox {
      stackpane {
        //first blue box
      }

      stackpane {
        //second green box
        svgpath("M600 0 L350 800 L900 800 Z") {
          addClass(UIStyles.bgImagesStyle)
        }
      }

      stackpane {
        //third red box
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And this all works well and good, but I need to scale the `svgpath` down a bit..

```
svgpath("M600 0 L350 800 L900 800 Z") {
  addClass(UIStyles.bgImagesStyle)
  scaleX = .4
  scaleY = .4
}
```

and then this happens:

[image]

I need the green box to adhere to the new, scaled-down bounds of the `svgpath`. Is there a way to "update" the width/height of the stackpane to the new bounds?

Thank you for any help!